# How many elements of finite order are there in $D_{\infty}$ and do any generate subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

**1.** Which elements of the infinite dihedral group have finite order?

**2.** Do any of these elements form a subgroup of $D_{\infty}$?

Comment: What description of $D_\infty$ are you working with? For example $D_\infty \cong C_2 * C_2$, and you can describe the finite order element in terms of the free factors, or you could be working with a concrete definition in terms of function on the real line etc. Your question is lacking some context and research effort.

Comment: I think it's pretty straight forward  for me now. See above.Who is OP?

Comment: @JacopoStifani You are, in this case :) "OP" is an abbreviation for Original Poster (or post). Now that the question has been reopened and you've got the idea, perhaps you could write up your own answer to the question here, as well.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Moved answer in question to answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s(x)=-x$ and $t(x)=x+1$ be the generators for $D_{\infty}=\{{s,t:s^2=e,st=t^{-1}s}\}$. Then elements $t^is$, where $i\in\mathbb{Z}$, have finite order, and $\{{e,s}\}$ and $\{{e,t^is}\}$ are subgroups of $D_{\infty}$. Hence, we have infinitely many elements of order 2 in $D_{\infty}$ and, correspondingly, infinitely many subgroups of order 2.

Comment: How will elements $t^i s$ have finite order?